# Closing and reopening a faulted DuplexClientBase WCF proxy in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Periodically, the duplex Net.TCP connection between our Silverlight application and our WCF web service will enter the faulted state -- for instance, due to transient network issues, or if the service crashes and restarts, things like that.  When that happens, I'd like to catch this, and re-open the connection.  Sounds straightforward, right?  You should be able to do something like this:

```
private void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client.CloseCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
                client = CreateClient();
            else
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
        };
    client.CloseAsync();
}
```

But when I try that the e.Error in the CloseCompleted handler has this exception:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

I've tried a whole bunch of variations on this same theme, including:

- Not closing the connection after it faults and just recreating it.
- Calling client.InnerChannel.Close() and/or client.ChannelFactory.Close() manually.
- calling client.InnerChannel.Dispose() and/or client.ChannelFactory.Dispose() manually.
- Lots of other stuff that I've forgotten now.

These strategies have resulted in a variety of errors, but none of have worked correctly, including the sort of non-Silverlight solutions mentioned, say, [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d8594a2e-4fbe-4d75-85ed-349e69f41697) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811142/reuse-a-client-class-in-wcf-after-it-is-faulted) (but all for regular CLR apps, not Silverlight). Surely this is a fairly straightforward thing to do, but apparently the channel caching is getting in my way.  What am I missing?  What's the right way to do this in Silverlight?  If this is a bug in Silverlight, what's the right workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things that seem to be working in inexplicable ways, the problem was my fault.  The actual code I'm working with is (not surprisingly, I hope) significantly more complicated than the simplified version I posted above.  And it turns out that in my real code, in the particular code path that I was testing, the equivalent of this line was never being called:

```
client = CreateClient();
```

In other words, the client wasn't actually getting recreated after throwing a fault, and the errors I was running into primarily resulted from trying to re-use an old instance. Sorry for the fuss.